# Storing a list within a data frame element in R

Tags: r, data-structures

I want to create a data structure in the form of

```
Start, End, Elements
  3  , 6  ,  {4,5}
  4 ,  10 ,  {7,8,9}
   ....
```

In words, I am moving a ball along a line. The "start" represents the left most position of the ball and the "End" represents the right most. The "Elements" means I somehow find those positions special. What is the best data structure to use when the number of elements can grow very large? The only thing I can think of is a data frame where the 3rd column is an appropriately formatted string. I would then have to parse the string if I wanted to look at each number in the set. Is there a better data format that R has or is that about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually this worked great and was easy to implement. Didn't realize that a dataframe can store a list inside. Perfect, thank you

Comment: why doesn't either @joran or the OP post this as an answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The option mentioned in my comment, i.e. simply using a list for one of the columns:

```
dat <- data.frame(Start = 3:4, End = c(6,10))
> dat
  Start End
1     3   6
2     4  10
> dat$Elements <- list(4:5,7:9)
> dat
  Start End Elements
1     3   6     4, 5
2     4  10  7, 8, 9
```

You could also of course ditch data frames entirely and simply use a plain old list (which might make more sense in a lot of cases, anyway):

```
list(list(Start = 3,End = 6, Elements = 4:5),list(Start = 4,End = 10,Elements = 7:9))
[[1]]
[[1]]$Start
[1] 3

[[1]]$End
[1] 6

[[1]]$Elements
[1] 4 5


[[2]]
[[2]]$Start
[1] 4

[[2]]$End
[1] 10

[[2]]$Elements
[1] 7 8 9
```

Comment: and if you use a `data.table`, you can do it all on one line: `data.table(Start = 3:4, End = c(6,10), Elements = list(4:5, 7:9))`

Comment: @eddi Yes, but then you have to use **data.table**. :p

Comment: not have to, **get to** - if it were up to me, there would be no more `data.frame`'s :)

Comment: Or, more directly: `dat <- data.frame(Start = 3:4, End = c(6,10), Elements = I(list(4:5, 7:9)))`

Answer (score 7):

You could store it as a tall data frame rather than a wide one, and probably use the `data.table` to process it efficiently. That is, make one row per element rather than one row per start-end pair

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(Start=c(3, 3, 4, 4, 4), End=c(6, 6, 10, 10, 10), Elements=c(4, 5, 7, 8, 9))
#   Start End Elements
#1:     3   6        4
#2:     3   6        5
#3:     4  10        7
#4:     4  10        8
#5:     4  10        9
```

This would let you do multiple kinds of processing on the data quite easily, such as determining how many elements are in each range:

```
dt[, list(Num.Elements=length(Elements)), by=c("Start", "End")]

#    Start End Num.Elements
# 1:     3   6            2
# 2:     4  10            3
```

This would also make the data easy to use for plots using the `ggplot` package, which usually expects data to be in a tall format.

You might note that this data structure wasteful since it repeats the Start and End for each element. However, data tables are stored very efficiently- even if your list of elements is literally millions long it can easily fit and be processed in this manner. Try a line like:

```
dt = data.table(Start=1:1e6, End=1:1e6, Elements=1:1e6)
```

for a demonstration. It would *certainly* be faster to deal with than keeping each element list as a string and splitting it each time.

Comment: I didn't realize that saving it as a list as joran mentioned above is an option. Now I just save it as a list of numeric elements which becomes easy to do. Thanks for the idea though, I wasn't even thinking of long format until you mentioned!